# webpack: alias does not work in HTML tags

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader, webpack-html-loader

Is there any reasons why the alias below does not work in HTML tags or work in JavaScript?

In my webpack config file:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/')
    }
  },
 ...
 ...
 ...

 {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'images',
          esModule: false,
          name: '../assets/images/[name].[ext]'
        },
      },
    ]
 },
 {
   test: /\.(html)$/,
   use: ['html-loader']
 }
```

In my HTML file (.vue):

```
// .vue
// Does not work
<template>
  <p><img src="~/assets/images/sample.jpg"></p>
</template>

// Ok
<script>
import Image from '~/assets/images/sample.jpg'
</script>
```

Am I missing something in my webpack configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue-html-loader` and `css-loader` are actually used in this case.

You can try this:

```html
<img class="logo" src="~assets/images/sample.jpg">
```

or

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="sample" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import image from '~/assets/images/sample.jpg';

export default {
    data() {
        sample: image;
    }
}
</script>
```